# Error in text mining: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, string, tm

The following for loop gives me an error which says `Error in nenv[i]/nref[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator`.

```
library(tm)
library(stringr)
mydata = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
          text=c("This is text mining exercise;Meta-analysis in envtal science",
                 "Text analysis is bit confusing;This is how the analysis works",
                 "Hint on this text analysis?;Highly appreciated!")) 
multiwords<-c("Text","analysis","bit confusing")
txt = frq = nenv = prnt = list() 
for(i in 1:length(mydata$id)){ 
    nref[i] = lengths(strsplit(as.character(mydata$text[i]),";"))
    txt[i] = str_extract_all(mydata$text[i],str_c(multiwords, collapse="|"))
    frq[i] = lapply(txt[i],table)
    nenv[i] = sum(unlist(frq[i]))
    prnt[i] = nenv[i]/nref[i]*100
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You are loading the tm package, and not making any use of it. What is your expected output. Please make a decent [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that `nenv[i]` and `nref[i]` are (elements of) lists. You could transform them into numerics by

```r
prnt[i] = as.numeric(nenv[i])/as.numeric(nref[i])*100
```

depending on the type you need. Alternatively you could `unlist` them.